# Seleccionar un contenedor padre(no directo) de un elemento con javascript

Tags: javascript, input

En un formulario que va anidando contenedores hasta llegar a un input, necesito saber como puedo llegar a localizar con javascript el que sería el contenedor principal por así llamarlo. Para cuando de un error ese input en las validaciones, añadirle una clase a ese contenedor principal.
Un ejemplo sería:

```
<div class="contenedor_principal">
   <div class="segundo_contenedor">
      <div class="tercer_contenedor">
         <div class="cuarto_contenedor">
            <input required class="input" type="text" name="input" id="input">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor_principal">
   <div class="segundo_contenedor">
      <div class="tercer_contenedor">
         <div class="cuarto_contenedor">
            <input required class="input_dos" type="text" name="input_dos" id="input_dos">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo lo que necesitaría es saber cuando uno de los dos input tenga un value erróneo, saber como llegar hasta el ".contenedor_principal" de ese input en concreto para a este añadirle una clase.

Comment: Intenta con el método [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 0):

El método nodo.closest(selector) asciende desde nodo hasta llegar al nodo que coincida con selector:

```
let myinput = document.getElementById('input')
let antecesor = myinput.closest(".contenedor_principal")
console.log(antecesor)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo conocía. Me ha servido perfecto